# What is 4’d# notation?

Tags: embedded

In an Atmel datasheet, I see a notation I've never seen before, for example:

> Register bits MAX_BE define the maximum value of the backoff exponent in the CSMA- CA algorithm. It equals macMaxBE; refer to section 7.5.1.4 of [2]. Valid values are [4’d8, 4’d7, ... , 4’d3].

How does one interpret/decode the 4’d# values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That looks like verilog to me (or at least it's the same format as verilog uses).

`4'd#` means a 4-bit field, with a decimal value of #.

So `4'd8` is binary `1000`.

Other number formats can be `'h` (hex representation), or `'b` (binary representation)

examples:

```
16'd1 = 0000000000000001
8'hff = 11111111
5'b10101 = 10101
```

(etc).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the notation is supposed to mean, but a similar datasheet for an [Analog Devices chip](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/AN-1082.pdf) lists the valid values as 3 to 8, so I'd guess the actual values this one wants are also 8,7,..3.

*Edit*
  I think Tim is right.